# Why would an arranger change a major G6 chord to a major C chord in second inversion?

Tags: sheet-music, arranging

I am studying Cold Play's "Don't Panic", and in the piano arrangement, the arranger has changed a major6 chord to an inverted chord with the same bass. Here is the score

[image: measure from "Don't Panic" score]

In the original recording of the song the chord is a G6 chord played on a guitar (about 0:50), so why would the arranger put that C there for the piano arrangement on that particular note? The arranger could have kept that B throughout the whole bar yet he/she decided to use C and change it halfway through the bar. Why?

Comment: The top staff is a vocal melody, but what are the other staves?

Comment: There's not enough information here to give a good answer to the question. At minimum: what is the song, and what happens in the measure before? (Also, the chords have the same "bass note", but they do not have the same "root". This is a critical distinction.)

Comment: Er, because he can? When there are specific notes at a point in a song, any chord that can fit is fair game. Here there's E and G (I think) so Em, A7, C, G6, Am7 are some options one could use. Or even chords that don't exactly contain both notes.

Comment: @piiperi bass and treble staves... sorry, thought that was obvious

Comment: @Aaron, you are right, I changed the word... my bad. The song is Don't panic by Coldplay and this happens in the bridge section about a minute or two in

Comment: @Tim What do you mean "because he can". The original song uses a G6 chord so there must be a good reason for making the change if the purpose is to arrange the music as faithfuly as possible

Comment: Clefs??? why are we supposed to guess and fill in the blanks? update the picture.

Comment: 'If that's the purpose' - but is it? I frequently re-harmonise songs - it's quite fun and sometimes challenging.He's an arranger, and that's what they sometimes decide to do. Arrange something differently. And it's not clear exactly *what* has been changed to what. Please post both editions, with a few bars before and after to help. Song name helps too.

Comment: Is that "fr 3" - like fret three - next to the chord diagram? I assume it is, but the picture is unclear

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - fr3 is standard for 'this is fret 3' in guitar chord windows.

Comment: @Tim, provided I can _read_ it, I can't tell if it's `fr3` or `fr5`

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - O.k., but if it was fr5 that would be a A chord - even more bizarre.

Comment: My point it to the OP to provide a clear to read example.

Comment: Just a brief comment to point out the importance of including 1) The song being asked about; 2) The measure number and/or position in a recording; 3) context beyond the specific note/chord in question. Without that information, Laurence's answer would be near impossible to give.

Comment: Yeah, I need clefs on your sheet music. Although the answers on this question imply a different story, I currently cannot help but think that **all 3 staves on your excerpt use the bass clef**, which would explain all the notes except the passing A in the topmost staff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I follow your question's concern, I think you are expecting the chords symbols to be...

`C/G` then `G6` or

`Gsus4` then `G6`

...because of the `C` in middle staff, first beat.

But the chord symbols are there to show what a *guitarist should play* rather than some kind non chord tone label or analysis.

The chord in this section is `G6` and their is a non-chord tone `C` resolving to a `B`.

Another way to think about this situation is a very old idea from figured bass harmony. A chord in second in version like `C/G` is a *harmonic* idea, basically dealing with chord roots. But figured bass looked at it as a *double appoggiatura* over a `G` bass, it look at it as a contrapuntal thing, it would be called a "chord of the sixth", but the `G` bass was the fundamental thing rather than a theoretical root of `C`.

From the figured bass, contrapuntal perspective the `C` is an embellishment to resolve, not really a proper chord tone.

If you go with the modern, harmonic, chord root perspective you should be identifying `6/4` chords in the four categories: cadential, passing, pedal, or arpeggiated. The example doesn't include before/after one chord so we can't really explore it this way.

This seem like a lot of theory to throw around. I think the simple idea is don't casually identify `6/4` chords. First suspect them as non-chord tone, contrapuntal elements, unless you can fit them clearly into one of the four harmonic categories.

Comment: Michael, you are right about what I was asking and I understand the different historical ways of looking at these non chord tones but I was more concerned as to why there is a non chord tone there in the piano arrangement if the G6 chord is played for the whole bar on the guitar and the guitar is what drives the track? Could there be a melody part that has altered that G chord in the 1st beat and because of that the arranger voiced the piano part so to include this melodic part?

Comment: also, when you say modern harmonic chord root perspective, I assume you don't really mean "modern" as in "today" since in real modern music there are other 6/4 chords other than these right?

Comment: My "modern" I mean the chord root theory from Rameau. That's from 1722, so not "today", but it's the origin of the theory of chord used right up til now. The four 6/4 chord types is taught in today's textbooks.

Comment: We're really "getting into the weeds" with questions about the arrangement. It may be good or bad. The important take away is the guitar chord are instructions for _what to play_ not analysis of harmony and NCT... at least they shouldn't be. Lots of Hal Leonard song books have chord symbols that clearly are trying to account for the NCTs of the melody. IMO that is a _terrible idea!_ The result is a song sheet that usually _sounds wrong_ if you play all the sus and add chords cluttering up the page.

Comment: A suggestion from my experience: use the arrangements you find as an _aid only_, then mod or write your own. Songbook arrangements can help you with transcription by ear of tricky parts. Usually the melody is correct. But the accompaniment won't be accurate. That's to be expected, these are arrangements not transcriptions of the original recordings. From the chord symbols I usually pay attention to only the _root_ and _major/minor_ quality, sometimes seventh chords. The rest I get by ear from a recording.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see, the arranger has written the following:

- Singer, sing these lyrics with this melody
- Guitarist, play this chord
- Pianist, play these notes

I don't recall any rule that states that if a guitarist plays a G6 chord, then a pianist absolutely must not play a C note, even for a fraction of a second.

**Chord symbols are not a harmonic analysis**: [What is the relation of guitar chords to actual notes in the measure?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/86556/what-is-the-relation-of-guitar-chords-to-actual-notes-in-the-measure/86558#86558)

It would be unrealistic to demand the C note to be reflected in the accompaniment chord symbols. It is perfectly fine to have a backing band play a chord - however they feel appropriate - and write other notes for other instruments. For example, for harmonizing a melody with a fixed sixth or third.

Edit. From the OP's comment I see that the real question is: *why wasn't the arranger faithful to the original recording*, which only has a guitar in that part, and the guitar does not play a C note. Well, who knows why that is, but it's an arranger's job and even *duty* to make some kind of a creative contribution. Without further information I have to assume that the arranger liked the sound of the added C note, and thought that it felt appropriate to have a piano play it at that point.

Edit2. After listening to the recording posted by Laurence, on the first "yeah" word, the lead guitar and the melody together play a distinct C chord, and the bass plays a G. The acoustic guitar in the background may or may not play a C on the first "yeah", it sounds like muted notes to me. The G or G6 chord, with a B note, is played only on the "do" word. The transcription or arrangement is OK, so your claim that it's not faithful to the recording must be based on a different version of the song, or something.

Comment: There is no pianist in that part of the song! The piano arrangement is an interpretation of the piece so that someone playing this on a piano can play the song. That is why I don't understand why the arranger has not been faithful to the G6 chord for the full measure.

Comment: Who knows? Maybe the arranger liked the sound of that? Maybe it was a mistake? That's what arranging is - deliberate modification or adaptation of a piece. If you don't make any sort of creative contribution, you shouldn't even deserve arranger credits.

Comment: Not when your task is to arrange it as faithfully as possible to the original recording. Anyhow, it still doesn't explain why for have the bar it is arranged faithfully while for the first few notes there is a C/G chord

Comment: Who says an arrangement must be faithful to the original? I read arrangements every day and few are that faithful.

Comment: Maybe Armani confused arrangement and transcription? :) Really, arranging means deliberate modification, adaptation, adjustment.

Comment: @armani, the point is to _not_ consider the group of tones `G C E` in beat one a proper chord. Just because the tones coincide don't make them a chord. If your point is the arrangement is _inaccurate_, then it's off topic, question to faithfully transcribe/arrange a song.

Comment: In this case, on the recording there are two distinct chords played.  It's easy to notate them properly with chord symbols.

Comment: @LaurencePayne After listening to the recording, I have to agree, there's a C/G chord hit before the G (or G6). I would even write accent marks for the hits, because it feels important for the arrangement that all players hit them in the same rhythm. Though the C chord is played by the electric lead guitar, and it's unclear if the acoustic guitar plays the C or just muted notes at that point. The transcription or arrangement posted in the question looks OK to me, if the piano is supposed to play the lead guitar's part and the guitar chords are what the acoustic is doing.

Answer (score 4):

Listen to the track.  This phrase occurs at 0'50".     I'm sure I hear two different chords.   Which means the piano part is correct.  The chord symbol is wrong.  Or, if you want to be polite, an over-simplification.

Now, what the actual intention was is another matter!  When that section returns near the end of the song the guitar plays something a bit different.  Maybe deep artistic intention, maybe just sloppiness.

Comment: Sounds to me at that point there's an awful edit been made!

Comment: And when that section returns at the end of the track it's played differently.

Comment: Can't listen to it for that long!

Answer (score 3):

First, I guess the author meant "... in particular that  CHORD...", instead of "... that NOTE...".
Second, the chord IS ACTUALLY a CMaj⁹ chord.  It's easier for a guitarist (guessing he's not proficient in harmony) to place the fingering shape of a G⁶ chord, finger 2 on 3rd fret.  However, for a full PIANO part, and much more if to improvise, the note "c" should be present to understand the SOUND of the moment.  (I play professionally both jazz guitar and piano, and am an arranger also).